# **UPDATE Issues with .SH file running Correctly

Tags: shell, automation, esxi

I am trying to use this script to be able to shut down my ESXi server based on network connectivity.  I found this script online, on the vmcommunity and no one seems to be having the same issues that I am.  When I run this script It returns syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "in").  However the in is there

```
allInterfaces=$(esxcfg-nics -l | grep vmnic | awk '{print $1}' | awk '$1=$1' OFS=" " RS=)
while [ $# -gt 0 ];
do
   case "$1" in
    -v)  verbose=1;;
    -t)  downCycles=$2; shift;;
    -i)  shift; break;;
    --)  shift; break;;
    -*)  errorLog "wrong parameter:" "$@" ;;
     *)  break;;
     esac
  done 
  shift
```

Any advice would be extremely helpful.  Below if the full script that I am trying to use.

```
#!/bin/bash
verbose=0 
downCycles=3
stateCounter="/tmp/auto-shutdown.counter"

log() {
  logger "auto-shutdown: $1"
  if [ $verbose -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$1"
  fi
}

errorLog() {
  logger "auto-shutdown error: $1"
  echo -e >&2 "\n$1\n"
  echo -e >&2 "auto-shutdown.sh: shutdown vmware ESXi if network interfaces are down for a number of cycles"
  echo -e >&2 "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  echo -e >&2 "usage: $0 [-v] [-t cycles] [-i vmnic# vmnic# ...]\n"
  echo -e >&2 "       -v: verbose\n"
  echo -e >&2 "   vmnic#: selected vmnic interfaces to monitor"
  echo -e >&2 "           defaults to all available interfaces\n"
  echo -e >&2 "   cycles: the down condition is reached, if all selected vmnic interfaces"
  echo -e >&2 "           have been down for <cycles> consecutive executions of this script\n"
  echo -e >&2 "(c) 2011-10-22 by Ralf Lueders, support@lrconsult.com"
  echo -e >&2 "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
  exit 1
}


if [ ! -e $stateCounter ]; then
  echo 0 > $stateCounter
  fi


allInterfaces=$(esxcfg-nics -l | grep vmnic | awk '{print $1}' | awk '$1=$1' OFS=" " RS=)
while [ $# -gt 0 ];
do
   case "$1" in
    -v)  verbose=1;;
    -t)  downCycles=$2; shift;;
    -i)  shift; break;;
    --)  shift; break;;
    -*)  errorLog "wrong parameter:" "$@" ;;
     *)  break;;
     esac
  done 
  shift

selectedInterfaces=$*
nosi=0
for interface in $selectedInterfaces; do
  if [ "$(expr "$allInterfaces" : ".*$interface.*")" -eq 0 ]; then
    errorLog "$0 error: interface $interface does not exist"
  fi
  nosi=$( $nosi + 1 )
  done

if [ ${#selectedInterfaces} -eq 0 ]; then
  selectedInterfaces=$allInterfaces
fi

if [ $verbose -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "monitoring interface(s) $selectedInterfaces ..."
fi

downState=1
for interface in $selectedInterfaces; do
  state=$(esxcfg-nics -l | grep "$interface" | awk '{print tolower($4)}')
  if [ "$state" = "up" ]; then
    downState=0
  fi
  done

count=$(cat $stateCounter)


if [ "$count" -eq "$downCycles" ]; then
  log "initiating system shutdown..."
  echo 0 > $stateCounter
  /sbin/shutdown.sh
  /sbin/poweroff
else
  if [ $downState -eq 1 ]; then
    count=$( $count + 1 )
    countDown=$( "$downCycles - $count" )
    log "the interface(s) $selectedInterfaces have now been down for $count cycles, $countDown cycles left before system shutdown."
  else
    count=0
  fi
fi
  echo $count > $stateCounter
```

I have used Charles' suggestions and I am no longer getting errors in ShellCheck.  However I am still getting the same error I encountered before where it say that I am missing an in that is clearly there.  Anyone see anything else that could be edited to solve this issue.  I am really not familiar with shell scripting at all, so any information would be helpful.

Comment: (1) Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here. (2) Please include only the *shortest code necessary to demonstrate a specific problem* in your question, as given in the [mre] definition; if you can test that the short snippet reproduces the problem on its own, there's no need for the larger code; if you *can't* test that, then the short snippet isn't suited to be used here at all. (3) That specific problem also needs to be explicitly called out, to make a question answerable.

Comment: ...here, http://shellcheck.net/ points out that you have a syntax error: Two separate `esac`s for your `case`. (Lots of other issues it calls out as well; ideally, you should fix all of them).

Comment: (In the larger code, your last `if` is also ended with a `done` instead of a `fi`; shellcheck identifies that automatically too, and is able to more comprehensively check the rest of your code after both of those syntax errors are resolved).

Comment: ...one issue that shellcheck *doesn't* identify, btw, is that your code is needlessly incompatible with POSIX-baseline implementations of `/bin/sh` on account of using `==` instead of `=`. There's only one POSIX-specified string comparison `test`/`[` operator, and that operator is `=`.

Comment: I have used your suggestions, Thank you Charles.  I am going to see what I can come up with

Comment: On the first response Charles I feel like I did those things, I understand that it was probably to much to put all of the code in there and I apologize if that is causing any confusion. My issue is with that small snippit at the beginning of the post and the issue I encounter is clearly defined that I can tell.

Comment: As your code is updated, it *doesn't* have a syntax error. There's a *logic* error because you have the `shift` after the `done` instead of before it, but the problem the question claims to be about doesn't happen.

Comment: See the code snippet (with that `shift`/`done` ordering correction) running successfully at https://ideone.com/3H5mMg

Comment: ...if I had to guess (and without a reproducer that lets me see your real error myself, I *do* have to guess), your real code probably fails because it's saved with DOS newlines instead of UNIX ones, so the `in` is instead seen as `$'in\r'` by the parser, which doesn't match the keyword.

Comment: ...if you run `bash -x yourscript` and you see a bunch of `$'\r'`s in the log it generates, then that's very certainly the problem. Open your script in vim, run `:set fileformat=unix` and save it (or run `dos2unix`, or similar as appropriate for whatever tools you're using), and it should go away.

Comment: Thank you Charles, This has solved my issue!

Comment: Unfortunately The script is not running on my ESXi box.  Has anyone else tried to use this script for graceful shutdown?  Working now on getting outputs of the nic

Comment: I have the issue completely resolved now.  local.sh had to be made executable.  Now My free EXSi shuts down machine and host gracefully with power failure.